# Is there a way to to create a "two layer VPN" virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, virtual-machine

I am running my internet connection on the non-Virtual Box machine on a VPN. I have now created a Windows 10 Virtual box (I do not think the OS really matters for this question).

Now if I connect my Virtual Box as its owner entity to the router — i.e it has its own IP address — and then run a VPN on that Virtual box does that give me "Two layers of VPN"?

I am guessing not because the router must view them as separate connections to give them separate IP addresses.

If that is the case is there a way to to create a "two layer VPN" virtual machine? In Virtual Box or anyone virtualization software?

Comment: Your host is connected to the outside with VPN.  Your guest (default) is using NAT so just on another internal subnet. It does not seem to me this adds any additional protection except that the Host probably does not have a DNS name server running to allow access to / from Guest on a named basis instead of using IP addresses.

Comment: My guess is set to use Bridge mode that disables the NAT feature on the modem and allows a router to function as a DHCP. I have also updated the question title to be clearer about what I am asking.

Comment: I have been using Virtual Machines for a very long time . NAT or Bridged machines are not any better protected than the Host machine.  Host only Guests are better protected but much more limited as well.

Comment: I think I phased the question wrong, I am really trying to create a VPN within the virtual machine that is then going through the VPN on the host machine. So host is on a VPN then the guess is on a different VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the way you have described it, no - you will end up with different VPNs for the different (virtual) hosts.

It is conceptually possible to run VPN's over VPNs, and there are lots of ways to do it.

One way would be to convert your router to a VPN client. Another would be to convert the networking on the server the VM is on so that it acts as a router (including NAT).

There are other ways but they are protocol and OS dependent. (As the "outer" VPN only needs to know the real route to the Outer VPNs endpoint and inner VPNs endpoint you can conceptually set up a routing table so the outer VPN only knows how to reach its remote VPN endpoint over the physical connection, and knows to route the Inner VPNs endpoint over its VPN connection. Then run the inner VPN as normal.

Another mechanism might be to use policy based routing and/or different nameapaces - effectively if you turn your VPN server into a NAT working you are emulating this behavior.

Whatever you do, watch out for MTU issues (ie the maximum size of packets). Each VPN reduces the maximum packet size that can be sent, and this can cause all kinds of interesting and non-intuitive problems.